# Does Linux kernel call kill syscall to send SIGSEGV to process?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I was trying to understand how SIGSEGV is delivered by the Linux kernel to a process:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257665/346011

From multiple sources, I've read that syscalls are meant to be called from userspace only (as opposed to calling them from kernel space).

So, from what I recall, the only way to generate a signal in Linux is by using the kill syscall. However, if the Linux kernel is not supposed to call syscalls, then how does it kill a process with SIGSEGV?

Comment: the only way to generate a signal in Linux **from userspace** is by using the kill syscall. But the kernel does it directly.  After all, the kernel has to *implement* the kill syscall somehow.

Comment: Signals are delivered at the transition from kernel mode to user mode. If a signal is outstanding, instead of switching to the normal user context the kernel instead switches to the signal handler. The default signal handler terminates the process with an error. A syscall is one reason for being in kernel mode, a memory violation interrupt is another.

Comment: The kernel code for delivering signals can be found in https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/signal.c